# Google oAuth not working on play store build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I have been developing a small react native app that uses firebases google oAuth for signin. The problem is that when I upload the app to the play store it wont even show a browser popup window when I press the "Signin with Google" button. The google sigin does work if I download the standalone apk version of my app directly from expo. I suspect that this error has something to do with the fact that google play console creates a new sha1 fingerprint. I have found a few people saying that I should add the sha1 fingerprint to my firebase project but that does not work since I am using google cloud for authentication. My question is how do I make the google sigin work on the play store version of my app, thanks in advance.

I tried logging in but no browser popup window appears.